# Cannot Get/ in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, get, body-parser

I am following this http://www.expertphp.in/article/user-login-and-registration-using-nodejs-and-mysql-with-example link

I get a cannot GET/ error and I have tried all the stackoverflow answers but it isn't getting solved.

```
var express=require("express");
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var authenticateController=require('./controllers/authenticate-controller');
var registerController=require('./controllers/register-controller');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
/* route to handle login and registration */
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {});
  });
app.post('/api/register',registerController.register);
app.post('/api/authenticate',authenticateController.authenticate);
app.listen(8012);
```

this is my current code

Comment: The path `/` is handled and returns an empty object `{}`. If you're really trying to get the error message, try remove the part of code where it says `app.get(...`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you're trying to send `index.html` at the path `/`. That is fine, but don't use `render` for that. Simply send `index.html` as such:

```
// replace this
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});
});
// by this
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('full/path/to/index.html'))
```

Useful links:

- [Express doc on res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)
- [Express doc on res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

1) reading `index.html` contents and serving it at root url:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const indexFileContent = fs.readFileSync('path/to/index.html'); // caching file content to variable, to avoid re-reading it
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(indexFileContent);
});
```

2) defining `ejs` renderer as `.html` file renderer too:

```
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs'); // make sure You've installed ejs:  npm i --save ejs
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); // defining html renderer engine

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));


// API controllers
const AuthController = require('./controllers/authenticate-controller');
const RegistrationController = require('./controllers/register-controller');

// API endpoints
app.post('/api/authenticate', AuthController.authenticate);
app.post('/api/register', RegistrationController.register);

app.listen(8012);
```

**Pros-cons:**

**1-st** example will simply **read** index.html **once** to **variable** and will serve that content, but will **need restarting** the app to re-read that file.

**2-nd** example is using `.html` files inside `views` folder as `ejs` files, that gives **opportunity** to pass **variables** to html files which is **better** that simply sending files, + You can include one html inside of another using  `<% include partials/header.ejs %>`

Comment: Second option is great, but the first has several flaws, starting by the fact that it's using sync programming in NodeJS, and that express has [a built-in function to serve files](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Comment: @NinoFiliu I'm not saying that Express does not have builtin function for sending files. I'm saying that You can cache the file contents into file and never do i/o with disk drive every time when request hits root route. Also You know that express has static file server middleware, and index.html is static file for that case. In fact as person who serves static files using NGinx I don't like `.sendFile` and `static` middlewares. So that's why I've done it wisely and cached the file. It makes difference when You DDOS `/` route and compare sendFile vs cached content serving

Comment: Oh, okay then! I didn't look at it that way, thanks for the tips :)